# Is there an equivalent to malloc_history in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, heap-corruption, malloc-history

I am facing a very hard to find bug. Basically what happens is, that one thread frees a memory block while another thread still has a reference to it (this is not my code which makes everything even harder...).

I am new on the Windows platform, but I already tried running it with the Application Verifier and PageHeap enabled - the problem there is, that the error does not happen anymore (probably because everything is slower now - so I am dealing with a classical race-condition). Under Linux I would try to use Valgrind for this kind of bug - but probably this would have the same effects than Application Verifier (not seeing the bug anymore..).

On Mac OS X I would use malloc_history to trace this bug. So is there an equivalent in Visual Studio or WinDbg? What I would like to do is the following:

- Run the program in the debugger until it breaks with a segfault
- Get the address of the freed object and from there get a stacktrace where the block actually got deleted.

Is this possible with some Windows/Visual Studio Tools?

Comment: I've never used it, but this tool looks like it has potential: http://drmemory.org/

Comment: A tool which Microsoft recommends is umdh https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-umdh-to-find-a-user-mode-memory-leak however it's less powerful than malloc_history and cannot output usage history for a memory address

Answer (score -1):

I would start by fixing this problem:

"that one thread frees a memory block while another thread still has a reference to it"

Comment: As far as I understand the question, he wants to track down the affected memory block/reference.

Comment: If there is a perfect tool for this job, I think he'll still need to fix the fact that threads are working on the same bit of memory without synchronization

Comment: This was the question: I need to find the thread that is freeing memory. Telling me "you should fix the bug to fix the bug" is not very helpful. What I need is a tool which can track calls to free() and tell me who actually called it with a particular argument. So yes I need to fix the fact that two threads are working on the same bit of memory without synchronization, but in order to do that I need to figure out WHICH threads these are and WHERE this happens. On Linux Valgrind would help me to find that, on OSX malloc_history - so is there something on Windows?

Comment: "I need to find the thread that is freeing memory" Is not a question.  If you add the synchronization code, you'll find who/where/what/when is the problem occurring.

Comment: Again: to add synchronization code you need to know who references the code where. We are not talking about class-objects getting freed where you just can just introduce locks somewhere in the methods. I am debugging a very ugly coded C++-program with a memory manager that simply handles pointers to memory - you can not just put locks somewhere because we are not talking about one variable (or code section) that gets accessed by several threads but about one thread that decides it can now delete some blocks which are in fact used in another thread.

Comment: This is why I repeat myself again: at the time one thread accesses freed memory, I want to know where this block got deleted. This is what malloc_history is for (this tool would not be there if you could always easily just add some synchronization code to solve memory problems) and I am looking for something similar on Windows.

Comment: 'free()' takes a pointer argument with same value that was used with call to 'malloc()' obviously you have some way of managing that pointer at a high scope. Add a global lock variable at the same level and then call a new debugging method that synchronizes access before all suspected calls to'free()'.  When someone tries to access while locked, you have your culprit. Your mind is the best tool.